# Fullcalendar update event and new event ajax call

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Hy guys, I have little problem. I was setup my Fullcalendar, connect with database and all showing good, now i have little problem with update and add new event (in 24 hours format and allday:false

Instead of alert(event.id + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' + '(should probably update your database)'); i need calling to my createevent.php?id=$id&start=$star&end=$end

My json:

```
[{"id":"2","title":"hair cut Mike","start":"2013-02-02T13:30:00+01:00","end":"2013-02-02T15:30:00+01:00","color":"blue","allDay":false},{"id":"1","title":"hair cut Steve","start":"2013-02-02T09:30:00+01:00","end":"2013-02-02T10:30:00+01:00","color":"red","allDay":false}]
```

Also i need this for creating new event, i was put selectable jQuery and then work (input dialog).

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,


        allDaySlot: true,
        allDayText: 'Volledige dag',
        firstHour: 8,
        slotMinutes: 30,
        defaultEventMinutes: 120,
        axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
        timeFormat: {
            agenda: 'H:mm{ - h:mm}'
        },
        dragOpacity: {
            agenda: .5
        },
        minTime: 0,
        maxTime: 24,

        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function (start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            if (title) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                    allDay: false
                },
                true // make the event "stick"

                );
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');


        },


        events: "json-events.php",

        eventDrop: function (event, delta) {
            alert(event.id + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                '(should probably update your database)');
        },
        timeFormat: 'H:mm',

        loading: function (bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loading').show();
            else $('#loading').hide();
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate again? Your english makes this impossible to understand

Comment: Ok, let's try again.

I want call my php (createevent.php?id=$eventid&start=$stardateandtime&end=$enddateandtime) file when user drag and drop event, now when user drag and drop event, browser show alert box, for example (2 was moved 7 days, should probably update your database).

Second question,

when user select time, I need calling (ajax) another php file (editevent.php=?id=eventid&start=$startdateandtime&end=$endtimeanddate), now when i select browser show me input box.

In my createevent.php and editevent.php is php code for update and insert received data to mySql database.

Answer (score 2):

Just use well documented [jQuery Ajax functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/) within the event handler !

```
    eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta) {
        // message to end user
        alert(event.id + ' was moved ' + dayDelta + ' days\n' +
            '- database will be updated now');

        /**
         * perform ajax call for db update
         */            
        jQuery.post(
            'createevent.php'
            , { 
                id: event.id
                , start: event.start
                , end: event.end
            }
        );                    
    }
```

You should also take a look at the [docu](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/) of fullcalendars drag/drop callbacks